# How to push a log file from a client to the server using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a web application which clients are using. 
Behind the scenes I'm generating logs on the clients' machine (because JavaScript or jQuery is running client side), but I'd like that log file to get to the server.

I don't have to use the input type as file.
*Last note*: I'd like to push this/these file(s) to the server without the user having to know about these files.

How can I do this? Is there any plugin I can use?

Comment: You can't magically get files from the client without the user knowing about it as that would be a major security risk ?

Comment: How are the log files being created?

Comment: How are you generating the log files on the client?

Comment: using applet... I don't have to use applet

Comment: You want to push file to server from client without any client interaction as using input type file. This is fortunately not possible. At first i'd say why then save log inside a client file, why not instead use kind of persistent strorage as local storage?

Comment: you are correct i have .dll module which plays important roll at client side so I don't have to write logs server because of latency factor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

through javascript you can do `form.submit()` if the form contains a [input type file](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_fileupload.asp) then the file will get uploaded to the corresponding server folder.

Else you can also use Ajax to upload file using libraries like http://code.google.com/p/upload-at-click/

Best solution will be using the [FileReader API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FFileReader)

Comment: but user has to provide file path. But without user intervention I want to upload it to server on button click

Comment: when you specify <input type="file">  the user is given a browse button and a textbox when he can either give a file path or browse a file in his pc

Comment: I am writing logs in client machine and logs are generating by .dll so they can't provide path of every time can we hardcode file path using input type file?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot upload files from a client without the user first selecting the file.  This is by design and cannot be bypassed.

Since you create the log files yourself (somehow), simply save a copy of the information that is posted to these files in a local variable or local storage of some sort, and send that instead.  It's a simple AJAX call to do this...

```
function sendLog(logdata) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "savelog.php/aspx/whatever",
        type: "post",
        data: {
            log: logdata
        }
    }).success(function() {
        alert("it worked!!");
    });
}
```

If you cannot save the log data to a local variable or storage then I don't see any way of doing this without user intervention.